# Gradle dependency Is not loaded with gradle tomcat plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-tomcat-plugin

I have

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.0'
```

in my dependencies, still getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/spi/LoggerFactoryBinder
```

when running

```
gradle clean tomcatRun
```

what is wrong with this tomcat class loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your tomcatRun task got a classpath from compile?

```
configurations{
    tomcatRun 
}

dependecies{
     compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.0'
     tomcatRun configurations.compile
}

tomcatRun{
    classpath = configurations.tomcatRun 
}
```

Comment: Well, this time the same. "Could not find method tomcatRun() for arguments [configuration ':frontend:compile'] on project ':frontend'."

Comment: Thanks for helping. I believe I am so close. Still something not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for you with tomcatRun, but for tomcastJasper, I added dependencies to the tomcat configuration where you set the tomcat version information:

```
dependencies {
   def tomcatVersion = '8.0.42'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}",
           "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
}
```